# Winter 16 issue? Tooling API queries not working from Triggers, Visualforce

Tags: tooling-api, bug, winter16

This looks like a Winter 16 issue, but would appreciate any other thoughts.  Queries of tooling api objects (such a FieldDefinition) return no results when run in a trigger or a VF page, but they do return results when run from Anonymous Apex.  The same queries work in Summer 15 orgs.

Here's a simple set of repro steps:

1. Prove this works in Summer 15. In a **Summer 15** dev org (or sandbox), run the following anonymous apex via developer console:

   ```
   list<FieldDefinition> defs = [select QualifiedApiName from FieldDefinition where EntityDefinition.QualifiedApiName = 'Account'];
   system.debug('defs: ' + defs);
   ```

   Inspect the log; confirm that the debug output includes a list of Account Fields.

   **Assertion**: Tooling API Query works in Anonymous Apex context in Summer 15.
2. While still in your **Summer 15** dev org (or sandbox): Create a trigger on Account:

   ```
   trigger ToolingTest on Account (before update) {
       list<FieldDefinition> defs = [select QualifiedApiName from FieldDefinition where EntityDefinition.QualifiedApiName = 'Account'];
        system.debug('defs: ' + defs);
   }
   ```

   Make sure Developer Console is still open in, and edit and save any account. Review the log; confirm that the debug output includes a list of Account Fields.

   **Assertion**: Tooling API Query works in Apex in trigger context in Summer 15.
3. In a **Winter 16** org (preview org or Sandbox), repeat step 1. Confirm that the debug output includes a list of Account Fields.

   **Assertion**: Tooling API Query works in Anonymous Apex context in Winter 16
4. In a **Winter 16** org (preview org or Sandbox), repeat step 2 Confirm that the debug output includes an EMPTY list.

   **Assertion**: Tooling API Query **does not work** in Apex in trigger context in Winter 16. This has also been tested in a Visualforce page with the same results.

Comment: Maybe it's a newly introduced permissions issue?

Comment: @AdrianLarson I wondered about perms as well.  I haven't found such a new perm yet (checking the UI and the release notes); also, my testing from Anonymous Apex was running as the same user as my trigger tests and my VF tests.

Comment: I've repeated the test and got the same result. Are you able to raise this as a bug to support?

Comment: Unfortunately no, I do not have access to a support plan for this project.  I have submitted via partner portal (closed) and in the Developer forum (partner support suggestion).  Hopefully that will get picked up.

Comment: @JasonClark Is this still a problem? I'll push it to Premier support if you want.

Comment: @DanielBallinger Thanks, that would be great.  I have just confirmed the bug still occurs in a Winter16 sandbox (on CS15).

Comment: @JasonClark There is now a Known Issue that you can follow for updates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has all the signs of being a bug in Winter 16. I've raised this as support case 12634999.

In terms of short term workarounds, you could try moving the SOQL query into a future or queueable apex. Might help to get out of the trigger context.

---

**Updates from support:**

10/15/2015 08:40:52 AM PDT

> Please note that [I] will escalate the case to Tier 3 support and keep you updated with the progress.

10/19/2015 11:22:44 AM PDT and
10/20/2015 07:54:02 AM PDT and
10/21/2015 06:51:20 AM PDT

> Please note that Tier 3 support is looking into the case and i will keep you updated with the progress again tomorrow morning.

10/22/2015 05:19:48 PM PDT

> Please note that RnD has acknowledged this issue as bug and are working on it (W-2795216)

10/27/2015 01:24:54 PM PDT

> Please find below the link for Known Issue.
>   https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p30000000eNxN

05/10/2016

> We are pleased to notify you that the following Known Issue has been resolved: [Query against FieldDefinition in Apex Trigger/Apex Class context returns no rows.](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p30000000eNxNAAU)
>   Thank you for being patient while we worked to address this issue. Please feel free to reach out to Customer Support if you have further questions.